# Aggregating by time in MongoDB

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb

My query groups data from a collection in time interval of four hours, like this:

```
MyData = pd.DataFrame(list(DB.MyData.aggregate([    
    { 
      "$group": {
        "_id": {
            "datetime":{
              "$toDate": {
                "$subtract": [
                  { "$toLong": "$datetime" },
                  { "$mod": [ { "$toLong": "$datetime" }, 1000 * 60 * 240 ] }
                ]
              }
            },
            "price": "$price",
            "amount": "$amount"
        },
      }
    },
    {
      "$replaceRoot": { "newRoot": "$_id"}
    }
    ]))).sort_values(by='datetime').drop_duplicates(subset=['price', 'datetime'])
```

Which will group my data and give the expected output, like this:

```
{"datetime": "2020-07-07 12:00" ...}
{"datetime": "2020-07-07 12:00" ...}
{"datetime": "2020-07-07 16:00" ...}
{"datetime": "2020-07-07 16:00" ...}
```

The only problem is that, on my code, i need different intervals, so something like this:

```
{"datetime": "2020-07-07 10:00" ...}
{"datetime": "2020-07-07 10:00" ...}
{"datetime": "2020-07-07 14:00" ...}
{"datetime": "2020-07-07 14:00" ...}
```

So my question is: how can i specify a starting date, so that i can get different intervals on the data i'm grouping?

Answer (score 0):

You can replace `{ "$toLong": "$datetime" }` with

```
{ "$subtract": [{ "$toLong": "$datetime" }, 1000 * 60 * 60 * 2] } // start 2 hours earlier
```

The `$group` stage should look like this

```
    { 
      "$group": {
        "_id": {
            "datetime":{
              "$toDate": {
                "$subtract": [
                  { "$subtract": [{ "$toLong": "$datetime" }, 1000 * 60 * 60 * 2] },
                  { "$mod": [ { "$toLong": "$datetime" }, 1000 * 60 * 240 ] }
                ]
              }
            },
            "price": "$price",
            "amount": "$amount"
        },
      }
    }
```